# How to middle all text using "inline-block" with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using `span` elements and would display in a line by `inline-block`. I tried to make all text(s) `Test 1`, `Test 2`... `Test 5` to middle of each square with `margin-top` or `padding-top`, but it didn't work.

Besides that, whenever the `height` of the square has been changed, the text is still stay at the middle of its square. Please let me know how to do it.

**Fiddle link**: **http://jsfiddle.net/xVnQ6/150/**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="legend">
  <span class="legendTest1"></span><span class="legendText">Test 1</span>
  <span class="legendTest2"></span><span class="legendText">Test 2</span>
  <span class="legendTest3"></span><span class="legendText">Test 3</span>
  <span class="legendTest4"></span><span class="legendText">Test 4</span>
  <span class="legendTest5"></span><span class="legendText">Test 5</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.legendTest1 {
  background-color: #DCDEE0;
}

.legendTest2 {
  background-color: #FF4739;
}

.legendTest3 {
  background-color: #FFCA4C;
}

.legendTest4 {
  background-color: #00AEEF;
}

.legendTest5 {
  background-color: #27AF8F;
}

#legend {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#legend span {
  display: inline-block;
}

#legend .legendText {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.legendTest1,
.legendTest2,
.legendTest3,
.legendTest4,
.legendTest5 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: trying adding a `line-height` to your div whose value should be equal to the value of the height of the square. Example if square height is 100px, give it a `line-height : 100px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.legendTest1 {
  background-color: #DCDEE0;
}

.legendTest2 {
  background-color: #FF4739;
}

.legendTest3 {
  background-color: #FFCA4C;
}

.legendTest4 {
  background-color: #00AEEF;
}

.legendTest5 {
  background-color: #27AF8F;
}

#legend {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#legend span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#legend .legendText {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.legendTest1,
.legendTest2,
.legendTest3,
.legendTest4,
.legendTest5 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="legend">
  <span class="legendTest1"></span><span class="legendText">Test 1</span>
  <span class="legendTest2"></span><span class="legendText">Test 2</span>
  <span class="legendTest3"></span><span class="legendText">Test 3</span>
  <span class="legendTest4"></span><span class="legendText">Test 4</span>
  <span class="legendTest5"></span><span class="legendText">Test 5</span>
</div>
```

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to your **span**.

Here is working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xVnQ6/156/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Might want to include the HTML in your snippet, or make it a simple code block. Clicking on "Run code snippet" does nothing...

Comment: @Bhavin Shah: It works very well. It means that I can change the text to `top`, `bottom` and so on with this property. Thanks very much!

Comment: @HuyDQ .. yes you can do as per your requirements. Happy Coding. :)